# Showing a function is continuous on a compact set

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Let $\Omega$ be bounded and open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $f \in C^1([0,T]\times \Omega).$

If $f(t, \cdot) \in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ for each $t$, how do I show that $f \in C^1([0,T]\times \overline{\Omega}).$

I am not sure that it is even true.

Answer (score 0):

Define $f:[0,1]\times B(0;1) \longrightarrow \mathbb R$, $f(t,x) = x$ if $t\neq T/2$ and $f(t,x)=0$ if $t=T/2$. It's is a counter example.

Comment: Thanks but that's not in $C^0([0,T]\times \Omega)$ is it?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm pretty sure that it was not a hypothesis when I read. Anyway, I'll think about this problem...

Comment: Yes, my bad. I'll think again